# How can I add symbols in slider labels?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to add symbols and math expressions to slider labels, e.g. instead of "Choose lambda:" I want the label to read "Choose λ:".  I've tried multiple variations of HTML and expression(), such as:

```
sliderInput ("lambda1", label=HTML("Choose &-lambda;:"), min=0, max=10, value=1.1, step=0.1)
```

with the hyphen removed (I put it there to defeat formatting in this editor).

and:

```
sliderInput("lambda1", label=expression(lambda), min=0, max=10, value=1.1, step=0.1).
```

In all cases the label displays as "`Choose &-lambda;:`" (without hyphen) rather than "Choose λ:".

I also need subscripts and superscripts, but haven't tried any code yet.  I presume that if I can get HTML symbols, I'll be able to format subscripts and such with the appropriate tags.

**Edit**
Sorry, I can't answer myself because I'm a new user.  I found an answer to the Greek symbols part of the question.  It's ironic, because I've been beating my head against this problem for a week, then an hour after posting the question on SO I figured it out.  D'oh!

Enclose the `HTML()` function with `div(HTML())`.  Thusly:

```
sliderInput ("lambda1", label=div(HTML("Choose &-lambda;:")), min=0, max=10, value=1.1, step=0.1),
```

again without the hyphen in &-lambda;.

That worked!

Comment: This is currently not possible: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/shiny-discuss/unYp_sKDBNk/discussion

Comment: I have just seen the end of your post, then my previous comment is wrong ! Thanks, we were several guys to search a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug reported [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/119), and has been fixed in the [development version](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/) of shiny. `HTML()` should work with the `sliderInput()` labels in shiny >= 0.9.0.